# Column conflicts with the type of other columns in the unpivot list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im pivoting `sys.[views]` into key value pairs to compare with values on another server for consistency testing.  Im running into an issue which returns the error.

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>
> The type of column "type" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Query:

```
SELECT
sourceUnpivoted.idServer,
sourceUnpivoted.sourceServerName,
sourceUnpivoted.name,
sourceUnpivoted.columnName,
sourceUnpivoted.columnValue
FROM (
SELECT 
CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS idServer,
CAST('thisOne' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS sourceServerName,
CAST('theDatabase' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS sourceDatabaseName,
CAST(name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS name,
CAST(object_id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS object_id,
CAST(principal_id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS principal_id,
CAST(schema_id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS schema_id,
CAST(parent_object_id AS VARCHAR(255)) AS parent_object_id,
CAST(type AS VARCHAR(255)) AS type,
CAST(type_desc AS VARCHAR(255)) AS type_desc,
CAST(create_date AS VARCHAR(255)) AS create_date,
CAST(lock_escalation_desc AS VARCHAR(255)) AS lock_escalation_desc
...
FROM noc_test.dbo.stage_sysTables
) AS databaseTables
UNPIVOT (
columnValue FOR columnName IN (
object_id,
principal_id,
schema_id,
parent_object_id,
type,
type_desc,
create_date,
lock_escalation_desc
) 
) AS sourceUnpivoted
```

Why does this not like `[type]`,`[type_desc]`,`[lock_escalation_desc]` ???
Ive also tried `CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),type) AS type`

Comment: Did you add all of those `<br>`s to your question by hand? If so, did you not hit a point where you thought "There has to be a better way"? If you're posting code, please highlight the block of it, and hit the `{}` code formatting button - it keeps line breaks, and adds syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: nice ill give that a try next time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's actually a collation issue. I can resolve it by changing these lines:

```
CAST([type] collate database_default AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [type], 
CAST(type_desc collate database_default AS VARCHAR(255)) AS type_desc, 
CAST(create_date AS VARCHAR(255)) AS create_date, 
CAST(lock_escalation_desc collate database_default AS VARCHAR(255)) AS lock_escalation_desc
```

The specific issue is that `name` is collated as `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, whereas the other 3 columns you mentioned are collated as `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` (At least, on my machine, I'm not sure what it would be like on a server/database with different default collation).

Comment: How to make it work in case of dynamic query like this: set @sql= 'SELECT max(col) FROM (SELECT cast('+@col+' as numeric(3,0)) selectedcols FROM table ) d unpivot(col FOR selectedcols IN ('+@col+')) unpiv'; exec (@sql)

Comment: This comment saved my day and lot of days of pain :)

Comment: What if You have Bit Type column ? How would you cast it ?

Answer (score 31):

This is one of the solution for this type error

1: create the this table

```
CREATE TABLE People
(
PersonId int, 
Firstname varchar(50), 
Lastname varchar(25)
)
```

2: Then insert

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES (1, 'Jim', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO People VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'Jones');
INSERT INTO People VALUES (3, 'Bob', 'Unicorn');
```

3: run this script you get the error

Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The type of column "Lastname" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

```
SELECT PersonId, ColumnName, Value
FROM People
unpivot(Value FOR ColumnName IN (FirstName, LastName)) unpiv;
```

4: the solution is you must use a subquery to first cast the Lastname column to have the same length as Firstname

```
SELECT PersonId, ColumnName, Value
FROM (
SELECT personid, firstname, cast(lastname AS VARCHAR(50)) lastname
FROM People
) d
unpivot(Value FOR ColumnName IN (FirstName, LastName)) unpiv;
```

Comment: Not working in case of dynamic query like this: set @sql= 'SELECT max(col) FROM (SELECT cast('+@col+' as numeric(3,0)) selectedcols FROM table ) d unpivot(col FOR selectedcols IN ('+@col+')) unpiv'; exec (@sql)

Comment: I was pulling my hair out between yesterday and this morning. I took another look at your answer and I was able to get my pivot working by referencing #4. The Length of my issue-column had to be the exact same length as the others I was pulling in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Beruk I had the same exact issue... I ended up having to wrap each column in my Derived Table as a Varchar(250) in the event my larger column in the set was maxed out at the 250.  Sort of a shame as I have fields in there that are just Char(1) and to have to cast all of them to a VARCHAR(250) is annoying just a bit EXTRA.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this same error and I just made all the columns in the table of the same data type - I had a mix of `int`, `varchar`, `nvarchar` of various lengths. Once I converted all the columns in my table to the same type - `nvarchar(255)` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The PIVOT/UNPIVOT clause is sensitive to the ANSI Padding Status of the column (right-click -> properties in SSMS) as well as the type, size and collation. Try specifying SET ANSI_PADDING ON|OFF in the session before adding or recreating the column in question so it matches the others in the PIVOT/UNPIVOT clause.

Comment: This answer made more sense to me than the above, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by right clicking on the column header and selecting change type "using locale". See attached screen shot

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyTau.png): [image: Screen shot]

Comment: I'm confused on how you used the Power Query editor to fix the SQL server issue. Do you have a direct query setup? I thought anything done in Power Query would not affect the source and now I'm a bit concerned with the work I have done through PowerBI.