# why i am getting binary or string data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below query in which i am inserting into the temporary table and when i try to run the query sql is throwing binary or string data would be truncated. But actually my data is in the range of defined `nvarchar(400)` for column `PhoneModel`.

```
CREATE TABLE #orders
(
    quoteHeaderId INT,
    PhoneModel nvarchar(400)
)

INSERT INTO #orders(quoteHeaderId, PhoneModel)
SELECT qh.QuoteHeaderId, 
   (Select ph.ModelName + ','  
    FROM t_handsetQuote h2
       INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit t1 on t1.PhoneAuditId = h2.QuotePhoneAuditId
       INNER JOIN t_phoneModel ph on t1.phoneModelid = ph.phoneModelid                                                  
    where qh.QuoteHeaderId = h2.QuoteHeaderId
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ) AS PhoneModel
FROM t_QuoteHeader qh
INNER JOIN t_handsetQuote h on qh.QuoteHeaderId = h.QuoteHeaderId
INNER JOIN t_CustomerAdditionalInformation ch on qh.CustomerId = ch.CustomerId 
and keyName ='SendUpdatesByEmail' AND ch.value = 'yes'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Answer (score 1):

I think the `nvarchar(400)` cannot handle the length of string you inserted to it.

How about changing your `PhoneModel nvarchar(400)` into `PhoneModel varchar(MAX)`

Answer (score 0):

run your select query without insert statement, and check the `len` of `ph.ModelName + ','`. it could be differ record by record.

Run your query and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to see what's causing the problem is to use select ... into:

```
SELECT qh.QuoteHeaderId, 
   (Select ph.ModelName + ','  
    FROM t_handsetQuote h2
       INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit t1 on t1.PhoneAuditId = h2.QuotePhoneAuditId
       INNER JOIN t_phoneModel ph on t1.phoneModelid = ph.phoneModelid                                                  
    where qh.QuoteHeaderId = h2.QuoteHeaderId
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ) AS PhoneModel
into #orders
FROM t_QuoteHeader qh
INNER JOIN t_handsetQuote h on qh.QuoteHeaderId = h.QuoteHeaderId
INNER JOIN t_CustomerAdditionalInformation ch on qh.CustomerId = ch.CustomerId 
and keyName ='SendUpdatesByEmail' AND ch.value = 'yes'
```

and then check the created table by ordering len(PhoneModel) desc