# Binary data truncate error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert data into a temp table from a `select` query. I have almost 100 columns in my select query. How would I know or is there any trick by which I could know that a specific column is causing the binary data truncate error?

My query is like:

```
Insert into #t1
   Select t1, t2,....
   From Table1
```

What I thought out is to include additional column for each of my column which will give me length of column. But issue is I will having additional 100 columns in my select. Then I have to individually check for max size for each column.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Comment: No, not really. It doesn't even have to be one individual column - there's a limit to the size of a table row (and large rows are a terrible idea anyway). Basically, `I have almost 100 columns in my select query.` is your problem. Why?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, SQL Server doesn't offer much help here. What I normally do is find the *smallest* `varchar` columns (those are the most likely to cause a truncation) and comment those out from my `insert` statement one by one - if the `insert` now suddenly runs, then this column was the culprit. Repeat until you find your problem column (or multiple problem columns)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing

```
Insert into #t1
Select t1, t2,....
From Table1
```

You can do:

```
Select t1, t2,....
into #t1
From Table1
```

And then you can check what happened with:

```
tempdb..sp_help #t1
```

That will show you the data types for each column.