# SqlTableDependency transaction error after increasing column size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I'm using `SqlTableDependency` to track table changes like this :

```
_dependency = new SqlTableDependency<IdeaInfo>(_ConnectionString, "Ideas");
_dependency.OnChanged += _dependency_OnChanged;
_dependency.Start();
```

things went very smoothly until i changed a column size on my listened table `"Ideas"`, and now I have the following error :

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

thrown by `tr_dbo_Ideas_234726bd-11d2-4fba-a470-98bd32905b0b`transaction automatically generated by dependency

It looks like the `Service Broker` does not aware of new column size !!!!

Someone can tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138107/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-terminated-sys)

Comment: It's the same error but it's thrown by another function