# how to Concat binary data and nvarchar in SQL

Tags: sql

I have data let say idmember like 1234, and want to update my record with adding 0000.
I tried using `'0000' + idmember` and the result is error.

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I want the result like this 00001234

Can you guys help me

Thanks

Comment: is idmember varchar field?

Comment: yes idmember nvarchar

Comment: nvarchar(max) or nvarchar(something) ?

Comment: data type is nvarchar(255)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I'm assuming SQL Server, given that a Google search of the verbatim error message seemed to bring up SQL Server results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> String or binary data would be truncated.

most likely is being caused by trying to update the `idmember` column with a string which cannot fit in the current width.  If you have any data there which is already taking up the full width, and you prepend `0000`, then it won't fit and you would see this error message.

To fix this, you need to increase the size of your `idmember` varchar field.  You will have to increase it by at least 4 characters, if not more, to make room for the `0000` which you want to prepend.

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable]
ALTER COLUMN [idmember] nvarchar(259)  -- or anything greater than 259
```

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Comment: idmember record only 6 digit, and column size 255. I just want to add 0000 to my all idmember

Comment: @Henry What does `SELECT MAX(LEN([idmember])) FROM [yourTable]` show you?

Comment: my max character is 6

Comment: I got your point :) my mistakes, Yes I increase the characters