# How to insert a string with ( / ) in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have string that contains a "/".

How can insert that string into database table column?

When I tried to insert record using simple query like :

```
insert into XYZ 
values (2567, '364722988', 'ABC', 'IL/ITO-CLVB DEPT APO AE')
```

I get an error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 14
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

When I remove "/" from my query it will allow me to enter data.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I already checked column length, it is not an issue here.

Comment: What's the length of the column?

Comment: if you try `IL\/ITO-CLVB`

Comment: I had already checked column length,  it is not an issue here.

Comment: And if you replace `/` with `Z` or something - then what? And please add the DDL of your table to the question.

Comment: What datatype is your column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Comment: Paste your table creation script. It should be an issue with your length

Comment: Datatype of column is nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: it is better to use `insert into XYZ (col1, col2, col3, cal4)
values (2567, '364722988', 'ABC', 'IL/ITO-CLVB DEPT APO AE'`). So the order of the columns is defined.

Comment: inserting / should not be an issue.... from the error message its the column size and the data length that's the issue... it is saying it will truncate the data, if not the last column check the length of the other 2 varchar columns that you are inserting

Comment: Since nobody else yet mentioned it....do you have an insert trigger on that table? Maybe that is where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 4):

**String or binary data truncated** error usually comes if table column length is less than data being inserted.

> Check length of your 4th column in table XYZ where you are inserting value '`IL/ITO-CLVB DEPT APO AE'`

Comment: this sql fiddle shows no issue inserting that string which leads me to venture that Surjit is correct: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12ce1/1