# Which column is causing "the conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to determine **which column** is causing the problem?  Yes, I can manually look through the objects I'm trying to insert/update and check all the properties but I'm looking for a more robust solution.  For example, SQL Server [now returns the truncated column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482685/185123).  Is there an equivalent for `datetime`'s?

> SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Yes, I'm sure I have a `System.DateTime` this is `System.DateTime.Minimum` and the column in SQL Server is defined as `datetime`.  I'm aware of [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1332513/185123) .

Comment: This isn't as simple as the truncated data issue. The conversion could be in the data, it could be in join predicates, it could be where predicates.

Comment: In SSMS, you can select the columns in question with TRY_CONVERT() and test for a null return, which should enable you to find exactly which rows have values in that column that won't convert correctly to datetime.

Comment: Look for dates before 1753 (without attempting to do the conversion.) Can you narrow it to a single expression or column?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this SqlException is that the minimum date returned by System.DateTime.Minimum is `01/01/0001` while SQL Server only supports datetimes starting from `01/01/1753`.

If I'm not mistaking, you could use `SqlDataTime.MinValue` in .NET which should solve your issue.