# Exception Handling in Dynamic SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In Dynamic SQL statement one @STU_ID value is failing to insert the data into another table. Here I need to know which @STU_ID if failing when execution.

```
CREATE PROC DATA_COPY
 (
 @SRC_TABLE VARCHAR(30),
 @DEST_TABLE VARCHAR(30)
 )
 AS
 DECLARE @STU_ID INT
 BEGIN
  DECLARE STUDENT_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT STU_ID FROM STUDENT

  OPEN STUDENT_CURSOR
        FETCH NEXT FROM STUDENT_CURSOR INTO @STU_ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

EXEC ('INSERT INTO '+@DEST_TABLE+'
    SELECT *
    FROM '+@SRC_TABLE+' 
    WHERE STU_ID='+@STU_ID)

        FETCH NEXT FROM STUDENT_CURSOR INTO @STU_ID
    END
    CLOSE STUDENT_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE STUDENT_CURSOR
 END
```

Can you help me how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so can you include it?  Most likely there is a case in which `SELECT * FROM '+@SRC_TABLE+' WHERE STU_ID='+@STU_ID` returns no results.  You should check to make sure there is data before performing the insert.  Also, you are inserting into a table based on SELECT *.  This is going to give you hell when the schema changes.

Comment: The Error is: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: I explicitly change the size of one column in destination table lower than the source table, in which my requirement is to get a message when i execute the Stored Procedure is "@STU_ID could't insert the data into destination table"

Comment: Your error seems to have nothing to do with the ID.  You are trying to insert data into a column that is not large enough to store the data you have in your variable.  Eg. your `@SRC_TABLE` column length's do not match `@DEST_TABLE`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779082/sqlexception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check which you shared the link

Answer (score 1):

You can capture data during the context of the error with [TRY CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC ('INSERT INTO '+@DEST_TABLE+'
    SELECT *
    FROM '+@SRC_TABLE+' 
    WHERE STU_ID='+@STU_ID)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'ERROR WITH VALUE @STU_ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@STU_ID)
END CATCH
```