# Casting Varchar to fixed length

Tags: sql-server, casting

Is there any issue with the following SQL? Here no length has been used while converting to varchar.

```
SELECT CAST('abc' AS varchar)
```

Should I use

```
 SELECT CAST('abc' AS varchar(3))
```

Comment: you should **NEVER** use just `varchar`, always specify a length.  Besides being just lazy, you should always size fields properly, it is just one of the ways the database protects the data's integrity.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not specify `varchar(n)` then `n` will be assumed to be 30. For example: If we run the query below, we get 30 chars of output.

```
CAST('01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789' as varchar)
```

Also have a look at the following [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your string does not exceed 30 characters, you're fine.
SQL Server will try to cast to the default length which is 30 characters.

If you try to cast a string that exceeds this length, your string will be truncated to 30 characters.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Example VARCHAR(35) = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -- 35 Characters
SELECT LEN(cast(@Example as varchar)) AS [Result]

Result
30
```

Comment: looks like there's an automatic truncation, rather than an error: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17670

Comment: Edited, thank you.  I referenced an incorrect article for the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the cast to insert the data to a column that has a fixed length the second statement will help you avoid the "string or binary data would be truncated" error by truncating the data

[SQLException : String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779082/sqlexception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)