# Error 'String or binary data would be truncated' in Microsoft SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, python-2.7

I got this error when inserting data to Microsoft SQL.

> error: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLParamData); [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')

FYI, I use Python 2.7 and `pyodbc` library.

What is that error about? What should I do to solve it?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Updated. If you can, please undo the downvote since I already update it. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can't undo it.

Comment: The error message says it all, you try to copy data too big to fit the target, so the data gets truncated. Now you have to find the failing assignment, and adjust it somehow.

Comment: enlarge your column where you're trying to put a string or binary in that's too long :)

Comment: and I think the downvote is for "no or too less research". When googling for "String or binary data would be truncated" I get >150k results. So it's okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLException : String or binary data would be truncated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779082/sqlexception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Comment: Yup, but it was nowhere in SO so I put it here and answer myself to make SO complete. Maybe it is considered inappropriate here.

Comment: for sure. I found 5-6 questions with this error-message

Comment: Maybe my search query was too specific.  Should have tried better

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on this link: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/string-or-binary-data-truncated/

> This error message appears when you try to insert a string with more characters than the column can maximal accommodate.

Comment: I've quoted the essence. I just refer the link to honor the original author

Answer (score 2):

figure out the issue using following step.
in your insert satement  ,use 'LEN' function to find the length of the input columns.

suppose you are selecting data from a temp table for input.
 use the below query to find out maximum size of that column and compare with the actual size of the column in your original table (table you are going to insert data).

```
    SELECT MAX(LEN(column1))
    FROM #yourInputData
```