# Dapper error "String or binary data would be truncated."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I am getting the error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

when running the following line of code. I can't determine why and everything I search regarding this error is with inserts, such as exceeding the char limit in the database table. The data types of the database match the object string to nvarchar, DateTime to datetime etc. The following line of code follows the query below and is where the error is thrown. I am using Dapper 2.0.123

```
var result = (await connection.QueryAsync<OutputWithIds>(commandDefinition)).ToList();
```

Stack Trace

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass190_0.<ReadAsync>b__1(Task t)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeRetryable[T](Func`2 moreFunc, TaskCompletionSource`1 source, IDisposable objectToDispose)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryAsync>d__33`1.MoveNext()
at OQCESIResultsUrl.Repository.OqcRepository.<GetStoredUrlsForManufacturingItemAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in ...
at OQCESIResultsUrl.Repository.OqcRepository.<GetStoredUrlsForManufacturingItemAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in ...
at OQCESIResultsUrl.UrlProviders.OqcUrlProvider.<ProvideUrlsForMeasurementAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in ...
at OQCESIResultsUrl.UrlProviders.MasterUrlProvider.<ProvideUrlsAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in ...
at OQCESIResultsUrl.Services.EsiResultsUrlRetrievalService.<GetEsiResultsUrlByMfgItemIds>d__2.MoveNext() in ...
at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_6>d.MoveNext() in ...
```

The query that is being run is as follows

```
await using var connection = GetOpenConnection(OQCDomain);
var commandDefinition = new CommandDefinition(@" 
                SELECT CASE WHEN ser.PromassDirectoryPath IS NOT NULL OR ser.PromassDirectoryPath != '' THEN '' 
                    ELSE 'No record found'
                    END [ErrorMessage], 
                    CASE WHEN ser.PromassDirectoryPath IS NOT NULL OR ser.PromassDirectoryPath != '' THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
                    END [Success], 
                    ser.PromassDirectoryPath [Url], 
                    ser.ProcessingDateTime, 
                    s.MfgItemId
                FROM dbo.Sample AS s WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.SampleESIResult AS ser WITH (NOLOCK) ON ser.SampleESIResultId = s.SampleESIResultId
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.QCProcessHistory AS QPH WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.QCContainerId = QPH.QCContainerId
                WHERE s.MfgItemId IN (@manufacturingItemId)
                    AND QPH.QCStatusId = 9 /* ESI Reviewed */
                GROUP BY s.MfgItemId, ser.ProcessingDateTime, ser.PromassDirectoryPath",
    parameters: new
    {
        manufacturingItemId = string.Join(',', measurementDetail)
    },
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The query does work when running it on the database directly, returning the expected results.

Object it's trying to map to is

```
public class OutputWithIds
{
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string? Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessingDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? MfgItemId { get; set; }
}
```

Data types in the database are

```
MfgItemId = int
ProcessingDateTime  = datetime
Url nvarchar(256)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have tried removing all but one of the select columns to try and narrow down which is causing the issue but all are throwing an error.

Comment: `nolock` isn't the automatic "go faster" switch you've been lead to believe, and you should stop using it everywhere by default. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2023/02/07/what-you-need-to-know-about-nolock/

Comment: Why do you `LEFT JOIN` to `QPH` when a row *must* be found?

Comment: Side note: Should you be using an `AND` instead of `OR` in the `ser.PromassDirectoryPath IS NOT NULL OR ser.PromassDirectoryPath != ''` condition? As written, both empty and non-empty `PromassDirectoryPath` string values would be considered valid, because both satisfy the `IS NOT NULL` part of the test. You could also code the test as `ISNULL(ser.PromassDirectoryPath, '') != ''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about behavoir of SQL Server with virtual fields, but for my experience in other databases, it can be related with your virtual field `[ErrorMessage]`.

Just try to think step-by-step:

SQL Server tries to extract very first row from the database, and has some value in the column `ser.PromassDirectoryPath`. So, in the virtual field `[ErrorMessage]` you will have empty value, i.e. null, i.e. CHAR(0) or CHAR(1).

On the second row, you don't have value in the `ser.PromassDirectoryPath` column, and SQL Server tries to put string line "No record found" into virtual field, which, as it already know, has type CHAR(0).

So, maybe it will be anouth to CAST datatype of this virtual column to the CHAR(50)?

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(50), CASE WHEN ser.PromassDirectoryPath IS NOT NULL OR ser.PromassDirectoryPath != '' THEN '' 
            ELSE 'No record found'
            END) [ErrorMessage], 
    CASE WHEN ser.Promas
```

I am not sure about right syntax for SQL Server, but I hope I was clear.

Comment: I have tried CONVERT and Cast and I am getting the same error. I have also tried moving the case down after the other select statements. All result in the same error.

CONVERT(nvarchar(50), CASE WHEN ser.PromassDirectoryPath IS NOT NULL OR ser.PromassDirectoryPath != '' THEN '' 
ELSE 'No record found'
END) [ErrorMessage],

Comment: @Steven did you check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779082/sqlexception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated) ? I think they have a lot of variants to resolve or debug your issue.

Comment: The topic you linked to is discussing inserts as opposed to reading from the db, unless I missed something.  Although stuff like that is what I found for this error when googling. Nothing for this error on a select. Does Dapper make a temp table or something like that , that might be causing an issue. Something that it's trying to insert it into but failing because of an inferred data type in an intermediate step before mapping to the object?

Comment: @Steven you right, the most often siruation, related with your case it is about modyfing the data. But in the topick, which I linked, they propose several methods to find the root of issue, for example find the [fields causing the issue "string or binary data would be truncated"](https://gist.github.com/mrameezraja/9f15ad624e2cba8ac24066cdf271453b). Also, they proposed get text of SQL query, which exactly will execute on the server-side...

Comment: @Steven, but... I saw something right now... you bind variable `manufacturingItemId` in the source code to the IN operator.... but, how SQL driver will work with it? Maybe it transfer this array to something like this? `WHERE s.MfgItemId IN ([1, 2, 3, ...])`

Comment: Some of the options in the topic I have tried with no luck. I have tried each field one by one and the query as a whole in code and SSMS. Code doesn't work but SSMS does. I will try some of the other options in there as well. As for the array issue I am doing a string.Join in the params just below the query. That should return `1,2,3,...`.

Comment: Can you change the SQL just to check how it works with one value? Something like this `WHERE s.MfgItemId = @manufacturingItemId`, and put into the `manufacturingItemId` just one value.

Comment: You got it! The IN statement is causing the issue when I make it = some value it worked!